# How to convert an ffmpeg texture to Open GL texture without copying to CPU memory

Tags: opengl, video, ffmpeg, gpu

This ffmpeg example demonstrates how to do hardware decoding: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/release/4.2/doc/examples/hw_decode.c

At line 109 it does this:

```
/* retrieve data from GPU to CPU */
            if ((ret = av_hwframe_transfer_data(sw_frame, frame, 0)) < 0) {
```

I want to avoid this because it takes time. Therefore, I need a way to reuse that decoded video, which is in GPU memory, to redo color conversion.

**How to transform the decoded texture in GPU memory to texture in Open GL without getting it back to CPU memory like in the code above?**

If the above is not possible, how to do color conversion in the decoded video using open gl? I heard that ffmpeg supports passing opengl shaders as input, so I guess it's possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For short: it's complicated.

Depending on the hardware backend that ffmpeg uses on your system you might need to do DirectX/CUDA/OpenGL interop. Let's assume that you're using the VDPAU backend and want to interop it with OpenGL. It looks like ffmpeg does not expose that functionality from its public interface in a documented way.

However, based on the [vdpau_transfer_data_from](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/hwcontext__vdpau_8c_source.html#l00292) implementation, it seems that you can retrieve the `VdpVideoSurface` from the `AVFrame` as follows:

```
VdpVideoSurface surf = (VdpVideoSurface)(uintptr_t)frame->data[3];
```

From here you can pass that to `VDPAURegisterVideoSurfaceNV` from the [NV_vdpau_interop](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NV/NV_vdpau_interop.txt) and [NV_vdpau_interop2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NV/NV_vdpau_interop2.txt) extensions to create OpenGL textures.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's much clearer now!! Actually, I plan to support the Jetson Nano board, so I guess I have to use CUDA. I've found the same method but for cuda: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/hwcontext_cuda.c#L197 but I don't see any "surface". I've also found interop for Direct X https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NV/ but not for CUDA. Maybe is a different file?

Comment: @LucasZanella: Isn't `(CUdeviceptr)src->data[i]` a pointer to your CUDA image? I don't know if it's possible to create an OpenGL texture directly from it, but you might be able to reduce the copying to be entirely on the GPU without going into the system memory..