# What are the alternative way to sacle video frame in ffmpeg?

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, video-processing

so, basically, I am rendering video using FFmpeg lib in c++. what are the optimization techniques that can use to render a fast frame, so I can get better o/p in video rendering?

```
// app data structure
typedef struct {
    AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx;
    int stream_idx;
    AVRational time_base;
    AVStream *video_stream;
    AVCodecContext *codec_ctx;
    AVCodecContext *pCodecCtxOrig;
    AVCodec *decoder;
    AVPacket *packet;
    AVFrame *av_frame;
    AVFrame *gl_frame;
    AVStream *pStream;
    struct SwsContext *conv_ctx;
} AppData;

 if (!data->conv_ctx) {
            data->conv_ctx = sws_getContext(data->codec_ctx->width,
                                            data->codec_ctx->height, data->codec_ctx->pix_fmt,
                                            data->codec_ctx->width, data->codec_ctx->height,
                                            AV_PIX_FMT_RGB0,
                                            SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        }
        if (!data->conv_ctx) {
            printf("Couldn't initialize sw scaler\n");
            return false;
        }

        sws_scale(data->conv_ctx, data->av_frame->data, data->av_frame->linesize, 0,
                  data->codec_ctx->height, data->gl_frame->data, data->gl_frame->linesize);
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, data->codec_ctx->width,
                        data->codec_ctx->height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                        data->gl_frame->data[0]);
```

this function is maping video frame which quite less efficent for me to map video frame.
how can I avoid sws_scale and map video frames in OpenGL?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `sws_scale` you can upload the data to a texture and do the color conversion in a fragment shader when drawing your frame to the destination. Since you may encounter many different formats in `codec_ctx->pix_fmt` you'll need to manually support many different conversions. For planar formats, like YUV420, you may need to create a separate texture per plane.

To improve further, if FFMPEG decodes on the GPU, you can avoid the GPU->CPU->GPU data roundtrip by using an appropriate interop between the FFMPEG backend and OpenGL. See [How to convert an ffmpeg texture to Open GL texture without copying to CPU memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57243087/277176). Needless to say, it is complicated due to the variety of different back-ends.